# Long Polling fallback with websocket spring initialization

Tags: java, spring, websocket, cometd

I am using Spring annotations to initialize my BayeuxServer. I enabled websocket by setting the transport in my Spring bean -

```
 BayeuxServerImpl bean = new BayeuxServerImpl();

 bean.setTransports(new WebSocketTransport(bean));
```

But now, when websocket connection fails or is disabled in `js($.cometd.websocketEnabled = false;)`, it's not falling back to long polling successfully. It throws error `"400 Unknown Bayeux Transport"` in firebug console.

I couldn't set `LongPollingTransport` in `setTransports` since `LongPollingTransport` is an abstract class in the library. I tried creating a class which extends `LongPollingTransport` and specifying it in the `setTransports` API, but that didn't work either. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. We need long polling to work in case websockets fail.

cometd version: 2.5.1

jetty version: 7.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `BayeuxServer.setTransports(...)` with just one transport, you basically disable any fall back capability since you are explicitly telling CometD to use 1 transport only.

Class `LongPollingTransport` has 2 subclasses depending on the specific mechanism to use; you may want to use class `JSONTransport`.

Note that the [CometD documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/) has an example of [how to setup WebSocket with Spring](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java_server_services_integration_spring) using XML, but it is enough to translate the XML into code to have it working with annotations.

Basically, it all boils down to:

```java
bayeuxServer.setTransports(new WebSocketTransport(bayeuxServer), new JSONTransport(bayeuxServer));
```

Comment: Thanks Simone. That worked. Actually I have tried that before but I think I used `JSONPTransport` instead of `JSONTrasport`. Didn't really pay attention to that. My bad. Thanks again!